# How to change the order of select options?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to put the value the user selects to the top of the select.

What I want is when the select is changed to "Africa", the list displayed on browser will be:

```
Africa
India
US
UK
```

When change to US I want the list to look like:

```
US
Africa
India
UK
```

```js
function myfunction() {
  var intCountry = '4';
  var objSelect = document.getElementById('Genre');
  var objInitialNode = objSelect.options[0];
  console.log(objSelect.length);

  //loop through options in select
  for (var j = 0; j < objSelect.length; j++) {
    console.log('J::' + j);
    if (objSelect.options[j].value == intCountry) {
      console.log(objSelect.options[j].value);
      objSelect.insertBefore(objSelect.options[j], objInitialNode.nextSibling);
      console.log('ssss');
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="Genre" onchange="myfunction()">
  <option value="1">India</option>
  <option value="2">US</option>
  <option value="3">UK</option>
  <option value="4">Africa</option>
</select>
```

Comment: So you want the selected option at the top, and then the rest of the options should just be alphabetically sorted?

Comment: it dosn't matter the order but preferabily the same it order it already have;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this way :

```js
const objSelect = document.getElementById('Genre')

objSelect.onchange =_=>
  {
  let
    optSelected = objSelect.querySelector(`option[value="${objSelect.value}"]`)
  , optFirst    = objSelect.querySelector(`option`)
    ;
  objSelect.insertBefore( optSelected, optFirst )
  }
```

```html
<select id="Genre">
  <option value="1">India</option>
  <option value="2">US</option>         
  <option value="3">UK</option>         
  <option value="4">Africa</option> 
</select>
```

> you can also do

```js
function myfunction( el )
  {
  let
    optSelected = el.querySelector(`option[value="${el.value}"]`)
  , optFirst    = el.querySelector(`option`)
    ;
  el.insertBefore( optSelected, optFirst )
  }
```

```html
<select  onchange="myfunction(this)">
  <option value="1">India</option>
  <option value="2">US</option>         
  <option value="3">UK</option>         
  <option value="4">Africa</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: That looks good, but that convoluted syntax to avoid using a second `let` chaps my hide. You've made four lines out of two.  Let's not even mention the underscore to save a parenthesis. :D

Comment: @isherwood this is just my version of the Whitesmiths style, it might sound weird, but if you have dozens of variables to declare those 2 extra lines are nothing, and if I put the commas in front of them it's to be sure they are not lacking behind. I also use elastic-tabstops ...

Comment: thanks really much it was what I'm looking for.... but i think you define two variable optSelected and optFirst, inizialize then and after in the select do the insertBefore, and don't have a duplicate becase the variable indeed are pointer to the element in the select ; Great thanks very a lot

Comment: @Mister Jojo it was what I'm looking fot (I cannot vote); unfortunately when I try do adapt to my enviroment it do not work because .... i don t know my be my javascript version is a little be older

Comment: @fraaanz what is your enviroment ?

Comment: @Mister Jojo I have resolved in this way: 
      var optSelected = 
       el.options[el.selectedIndex] ;
 var optFirst    = el.querySelector("option");
 el.insertBefore( optSelected, optFirst );


That give me error and I do not know if it was for the missed ] or because do not recognize the word let;
Anyway for now many thanks (whit out your Help I think I cannot get out of)

Comment: @fraaanz you can try to change the `let` by a `var`, but anyway I think [**mstephen19**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69562096/how-to-change-the-order-of-select-options/69563471#69563471) have a good answer for your problem, [you must choose it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler solution than the ones provided in the previous answers.

```js
const obj = document.querySelector('#genre')

obj.onchange = _=> {
    obj.insertBefore(obj.options[obj.selectedIndex], obj[0])
};
```

```html
<select id="genre">
  <option value="1">India</option>
  <option value="2">US</option>         
  <option value="3">UK</option>         
  <option value="4">Africa</option> 
</select>
```